# Overriding all existing CSS styles?

Tags: css

I have one simple question that I couldn't find a definitive answer for as of yet. I want to change the styling of a website that already has extensive CSS applied. I cannot remove or edit these existing files, only add my own. Is there a way to override all existing CSS styles, or even remove them, through a new file? Or is the only solution to override each style individually, by using more specific selectors, the `!important` keyword, and so on?

I am very new to web design, so I hope you'll forgive this (maybe very simple) question.

Comment: I don't think you can do that easily with css. There are some [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252839/simplest-way-to-remove-all-the-styles-in-a-page) solutions though. Is that an option for you?

Comment: That's what I thought, even though I hoped there would be a simple solution. Sadly, I can't use JavaScript in my situation, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: Use JS... you'll remove the majority of your headache

Comment: @ViaTech
While I appreciate the answer and attempt to help, it's like I said: That's not what I'm asking for, because I cannot do that. All I can do is add a CSS file.

Comment: @RalphBear Then your only solution is to place your CSS below the CSS you want to override...CSS that is rendered closest above the element is used so if you have a `.my_color{color:blue}` defined in `third_party.css` you can place a `main.css` beneath that with `.my_color{color: green}` and any element with that class would end up having green text...does that work?... you just have to override the classes you wish...this is a lot how companies like MDBoostrap do their extra design (well with extra JS)

Answer (score 1):

yes important can override it but there are specificity overriding also.
Example

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="test-wrapper">
   <div class="box s-1 h-1">

   </div>
  </div>
</div>


.main .test-wrapper .box{}
```

if I want to override this

*increase the specificity*

```
.main .test-wrapper .box.s-1{}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. My problem is that I can only add a CSS file, not edit any existing files or add any HTML or JavaScript. Like I said, the only solution I'm aware of is using more specific selectors to override the styles. However, that would be very tedious, which is why I posted this question.

Comment: you can increase the specificity with existing elements also, thats what i meant

Comment: But in your example, you add a new HTML class, which I cannot do.

Comment: yes increase the specificity ill edit the answer

Comment: Why is !important not recommended?

Comment: once its used , in future if you want to override that again you have use important..and in a collective view its not good for a website to have many important..